# Returning different types in haskell

Tags: haskell, types

I am somewhat new to Haskell and am working on a project where I have the following code:

```
data Nested a = Elem a | Nested [Nested a] deriving (Eq, Show)
data Symbol a = Value a | Transformation (a -> a -> a) deriving (Show)


toSymbol :: [Char] -> Nested (Symbol Integer)
toSymbol x  
|all isDigit x = Elem (Value (strToInt x))
|x == "+" = Elem (Transformation (\x y -> x + y))
```

Is there a way I can avoid the type of this function being restricted to Nested (Symbol Integer)? I would like to be use Symbol to represent many different types, and have a function toSymbol something along the lines of the following:

```
toSymbol x  
|x == "1" = Elem (Value 1)
|x == "+" = Elem (Transformation (\x y -> x + y))
|x == "exampleword" = Elem (Value "word")
|x == "concatenate()" = Elem (Transformation concatTwoStrings)
```

I have no idea what the type signature for a function like this could be. Is there anything I can do to gain functionality similar to this?

Comment: Nah, this could only work by completely circumventing the type system. You want to use a dynamic language for that kind of stuff. The Haskell way would be not to start from strings in the first place, but from Haskell code as a DSL; then the compiler can deduce the types statically and you get full type-safety, without much extra syntax. Or start from some kind of custom tree ADT structure. But not from plain strings! If you need to save some data in a file, [there's libraries for that](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cereal), but I wouldn't bother with the details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are not able to figure out the type signature is because what you are trying to do it "making the return type of the function depend on the value of the passed string aka dependent type programming", the value of the string will be only available at runtime.

So basically if you try to say : `toSymbol :: String -> Nested (Symbol a)` , the `a` depends on the runtime value of the string and that why compiler complains about it.

There are many ways to *refine* your types so that all pieces fits together, one possible solution is to use a new type which specifies the different type of value a symbol could have. Below is the example:

```
data Nested a = Elem a | Nested [Nested a] deriving (Eq, Show)
data Symbol a = Value a | Transformation (a -> a -> a)
data SymbolType = SInteger Integer | SString String

addSymbols :: SymbolType -> SymbolType -> SymbolType
addSymbols (SInteger a) (SInteger b) = SInteger (a+b)
addSymbols _ _ = error "Not possible"

concatSymbols :: SymbolType -> SymbolType -> SymbolType
concatSymbols (SString a) (SString b) = SString (a++b)
concatSymbols _ _ = error "Not possible"

toSymbol :: String -> Nested (Symbol SymbolType)
toSymbol x  
  |x == "1" = Elem (Value (SInteger 1))
  |x == "+" = Elem (Transformation addSymbols)
  |x == "exampleword" = Elem (Value (SString "word"))
  |x == "concatenate()" = Elem (Transformation concatSymbols)
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it is possible to write a single function to do it. One possible solution is to use type classes, which keeps the single function API:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

...

class Token a where
    toSymbol :: String -> Nested a

instance Token (Symbol Integer) where
    toSymbol x
        |all isDigit x = Elem (Value (read x))
        |x == "+" = Elem (Transformation (\x y -> x + y))
        |otherwise = error "Wrong type"

instance Token (Symbol String) where
    toSymbol "exampleword" = Elem (Value "word")
    toSymbol "concatenate()" = Elem (Transformation (++))
    toSymbol _ = error "Wrong type"
```